# unable to draw chart of highest sold products

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I have a soldproduct table I want to draw the chart of the top 10 highest sold products.

trying it with following code but I don't know what is the exact problem while, it is logically right.

here is the error

> System.ArgumentException: 'DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType. Parameter name: input'

```
       DateTime start = startDate.Value;
       DateTime end   = EndDate.Value;            
        var TopTen = (from q in db.soldProduct                          
                      where (q.addDate >= start && q.addDate <= end)
                      orderby q.Barcode.Count() descending
                      select new 
                      {
                          count = q.Barcode.Count(),
                          q.productName
                      }).Take(10);

        foreach (var item in TopTen)
        {
            chartCustomer.Series["Customer"].Points.AddXY(item.productName, item.count);

        }
```

ADDED :- I have in each row the item name and the quantity which might be one or more, I want to add that as well to the query but it is getting harder

model of the bill of soldProduct contains the following

```
 public string barcode {get;set;}
 public int productId{get;set;}
 public string productName{get;set;}
 public int quantity{get;set;}
 public DateTime  addDate{get;set;}
 public double amount{get;set}
```

so the table if it has the following data

| productId | barcode | productName | quantity | addDate | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | milk | 3 | 3/2/2020 | 15 |
| 1 | 111 | milk | 1 | 3/2/2020 | 5 |
| 2 | 222 | bread | 5 | 3/2/2020 | 20 |
| 3 | 333 | cheese | 1 | 3/2/2020 | 100 |
| 1 | 111 | milk | 3 | 3/2/2020 | 15 |
| 2 | 222 | bread | 3 | 3/2/2020 | 15 |

quantity of the of item sold the highest is bread with 8 occurrences it should come first then milk with 7 occurrences and then cheese.

Comment: What LINQ: LINQ to SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x? What is `Barcode`?

Comment: linq  to sql server , product barcode is varchar

Comment: There is no linq to sql server - do you mean linq to sql, or are you using entity framework?

Comment: There is no C# type `varchar` - if `Barcode` is a `string` then what do you expect `Count()` on a `string` to return?

Comment: I am using entity framework to sql server database

Comment: varchar in sql server database and string in c#, when using sql if you select count it returns the number of rows that matches the query right so I used it in that sense , any alternative way to query the same

Comment: In C#, types are your friend. If the type of `Barcode` is `string`, then `Count()` will return the length of the `string`. Your query only has one filter, so there is no sensible way to sort by the number of rows matching - that is just a single number - so what are you trying to do?

Comment: q.Barcode.Count() returns the number of occurrence of the single barcode in the table based on that I wanna get the highest 10 products barcode that was sold during specific date

Comment: _no, it doesn't_. In C#, types are your friend. If the type of `q.Barcode` is `string`, then `q.Barcode.Count()` is the number of `char`s in the `string`. If you want to count the number of occurrences of each `Barcode` `string` in the query, you must `GroupBy` the `Barcode`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Addition after comments:**
 Apparently every SoldProduct has a property Amount. You don't want to count the number of SoldProducts, but the total Amount of all SoldProducts.

So if SoldProduct[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-5.0) for product "Milk" has Amount 10 and SoldProduct[22] for product "Milk" has Amount 14, you want as result that of product "Milk" 24 items have been sold (= 10 + 14).
**End addition after comment**

So you have a table, `SoldProducts`. Every row in this table represents one Sale of a Product.

table SoldProducts has a.o. at least the following columns

- `AddDate`: when was the sale
- `ProductName`: the Name of the sold product,
- `Amount`: the number of sold products in this sale.

> I want ... the top 10 highest sold products

"highest sold products" probably doesn't have to do anything to do with the height of the sold products, but with the total Amount of products sold.

To calculate this, you need to make groups of SoldProducts with the same name. You'll get groups of the soldProducts with name: "Bread" and SoldProducts with name "Milk", etc.

Then you want to sum the total Amount of all soldProducts per group.

So if group "Bread" has 3 SoldProducts with Amounts 10, 7, 5, then you want as result: ["Bread", 22]. 22 is the total number of Breads sold.
You order the result of the grouping items by descending TotalAmount and take the first 10 items.

To group elements based on something common is done by one of the overloads of [Enumerable.GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-5.0). In this case, I take the overload with parameter resultSelector to count the number of elements in each group.

```
DateTime beginDate = ...
DateTime endDate = ...
var topTenSoldProductNames = dbContext.SoldProducts
    .Where(soldProduct => beginDate <= soldProduct.AddDate
                       && endDate >= soldProduct.AddDate)
    // make groups with same ProductName
    .GroupBy(soldProduct => soldProduct.ProductName,

    // parameter resultSelector: take each ProductName, 
    // and all SoldProducts with this ProductName to make one new
    (productName, soldProductsWithThisProductName) => new
    {
        Name = productName,

        TotalAmount = soldProductsWithThisProductName
            .Select(soldProduct => soldProduct.Amount)
            .Sum(),
    })

    // order by descending TotalAmount, and take the first 10
    .OrderByDescending(groupResult => groupResult.TotalAmount)
    .Take(10);
```

Comment: this is very good logic I appreciate it , one last thing please If I have the quantity of item sold in each row it might be one or more ,each bill will contain single item by name but quantity  any way to add that in your beautiful query before I tag it as answer

Comment: thank you @Harald Coppoolse it is based on the item quantity occurrences , I had added a table above to make it more clear , if we check based on the amount some items would have more value but one occurrence(the sold quantity) , that is why I have to count the quantity occurrences it will show many items we sold

Comment: By now you should know what to do. Apparently BarCode is some identification of your product, so you should group by BarCode: checking for same int is faster then checking for same text. You should not sum the Amounts, but the Quantities

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong, you are returning count of chars. And without grouping this query is useless.

```cs
var groupingQuery = 
   from q in db.soldProduct                          
   where (q.addDate >= start && q.addDate <= end)
   group q by q.productName into g
   select new
   {
      productName = g.Key,
      count = g.Count(),
   };

var TopTen = groupingQuery.OrderByDescending(x => x.count).Take(10);
```

Comment: thank you , can you please check the added notes in the question

Comment: Maybe it is time to add your model to the question.

Comment: Add quantity to this query? As Sum?